# Passing optional parameter value from laravel route to controller

Tags: parameters, controller, routes, laravel, option-type

How can I pass optional parameter from laravel route to controller? I am using:

```
Route::get('test/{id?}', function($id = 5){});
```

But it is not working...

**Update: Laravel version 4**

Code is working now but my Backbone.js script which is in my view don't work. It will not fetch data from server (returning error).

Route:

```
Route::get('test/{id?}', 'TestController@index', function ($id = 5) {});
```

Controller:

```
public function index()
{
    $pitanja = DB::select('select * from pitanja ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 15');
    $znakovi = DB::select('select * from znakovi ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 15');

    Cache::forever('pitanja', $pitanja);
    Cache::forever('znakovi', $znakovi);

    return View::make('test.index', compact('pitanja'), compact('znakovi'));
}
```

When my URL is `/test/4` my Backbone.js code won't fetch from server (from this function) :

```
public function pitanja()
{
    $pitanja =  Cache::get('pitanja');
    return $pitanja;
}
```

(URL in Backbone.js controller is `url:'/testovi/pitanja'`)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, misread.

You need to check the order of your routes.

```
Route::get('test/{a?}', function($a = '0') {
  echo $a;
});
```

works fine for me.

Comment: I want it to be optional route parameter as in laravel 4 documentation:    

http://laravel.com/docs/routing

It work's when I do it like in previous post but my backbone.js code won't work (It can't fetch data from server).

Comment: Updated answer, sorry misread your question. Check the order of your routes. Try placing that at the TOP of your routes.php.